# What does K stand for in frequency analysis

Tags: encryption, frequency-analysis

It was from frequency analysis lecture and the professor mentioned but I cannot recall.
The K value for English was .067, German was .076. The lowest K was Russian which was .056. When the frequency is uniform among 26 letters, then K is .038.
What is the complete word that K stands for?

Answer (score 2):

It probably refers to the [Index of coincidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_coincidence), or more accurately the un-normalized index of coincidence, referred to in the Wikipedia article as "kappa-plaintext".

Comment: Thanks! So do you mean it is probably from kappa? I am looking for a word than sounds beginning with K and mean something like I mentioned above.

Comment: Yeah, I would guess that K stands for kappa in this instance.